# $\int \sqrt{x^2-1}$ using $x=\cosh(t)$

Tags: real-analysis

Please how I can find $\int \sqrt{x^2-1} dx $?

It is recommended to put $x=\cosh(t)$, it means that $dx=\sinh(t) dt$

$$
\int \sqrt{\cosh^2(t)-1}. \sinh(t) dt=\int\sinh^2(t) dt=\int \cosh(2t)dt-\int \frac12 dt
$$

We can find the result like this? How to continue?

Answer (score 0):

$\int \cosh (2t)dt=\int \frac {e^{2t}+e^{-2t}} 2 dt=\frac 1 4 (e^{2t}-e^{-2t})+C$.

Comment: is it the same result where the consider x=sec(u) ?

Comment: I think it is harder if you use $x=\sec u$. @lindaOiladali

Comment: but when I see I Wolfram alpha I don't find the same result

Comment: Some times the answers involving trigonometric functions look different but they are one and the same.

Answer (score 0):

Proceeding from where you left, we have
$$\int\cosh(2t)dt = \dfrac{1}{2}\sinh(2t)+C$$
and
$$\int\dfrac12dt = \dfrac{t}{2} +C.$$
The first follows from $\sinh' = \cosh$.

This gives your integral to be
$$\dfrac{1}{2}(\sinh(2t) + t).$$
Substitute back to get the final answer.

Comment: what is $\sinh(2\argsh(x))$ ? please

Comment: Use $\sinh(2a) = 2\sinh(a)\cosh(a)$ and $\cosh a = \sqrt{1+\sinh^2a}$.